# Axon - publishing event from ListenerInvocationErrorHandler is not resolved properly by SagaEventHandler with an associatedProperty

Tags: java, axon

I'm trying to send an event from a registered `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`, the handler is attached to each type of saga via `subscribingSagaManager()` and is registered like this:

```java
private static <S extends BasicSaga> SagaConfiguration<S> registerSaga(Class<S> sagaType) {
    return SagaConfiguration.subscribingSagaManager(sagaType).configureListenerInvocationErrorHandler(...)
}
```

Catching the error and sending the event here:

```java
private static ListenerInvocationErrorHandler getListenerInvocationErrorHandler(EventBus eventBus) {
    // code below is the callback for errors
    return (Exception e, EventMessage<?> event, EventListener eventListener) -> {
        ...
        eventBus.publish(new GenericEventMessage<>(new Events.someEvent(myProperty)));
    }
}
```

When this code is hit the associationProperty is null and the saga inforamtion is not resolved.

```java
@EndSaga
@SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "myProp")
public void doSomething(Events.someEvent) {
    ...
    // Should resolve the associationProperty, but when debugged the value is null.
}
```

My event is populated with all of the correct fields, and the associationProperty on the event is NOT null.

Is it possible that this happens because the Saga ended?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Given the current set of information I find it hard to pinpoint where the problem could lie. Would you by any chance have a repository containing the sample code showcasing the issue?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm unable to share the repository since it is located in an air gapped network, what other information can I provide in order to help you? @Steven

Comment: Was mainly asking this as debugging this myself would give me the best understanding what's the issue. Not requesting access to the actual repository, but more so a sample project on your local GitHub (for example) which consistently fails in a similar vein.
Regardless, updating your question with the following would be helpful:(1) Axon version, (2) Spring yes/no, (3) AxonServer yes/no, (4) if there's any additional `EventBus`/`EventStore` configuration in place, (5) do you have any stack traces / exceptions occurring, (6) is the referenced event actually stored yes/no.